# Overcoming procrastination & the fear of making decision.

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

I wanted to know any philosopher who addresses procrastination. & who deals with the overcoming fears such as decision making ? Much appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be more psychology than phil. mind... Try Kierkegaard.

Comment: Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As @Virmaior suggested, the existentialists, particularly Kierkegaard and Sartre, are the philosophers who probably most directly wrestled with the subject --not procrastination, *per se,* but decision-making, and overcoming fear of commitment.

You might read Kierkegaard's *Either/Or,* *Fear and Trembling,* and *Repetition,* and also look into his concept of "[the leap of faith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_of_faith)."  Walker Percy's well-known novel *The Moviegoer* provides [a dramatization of some of these same ideas](http://popculturephilosopher.com/kierkegaards-narrative/).

For Sartre, you might read his classic play [*No Exit*](https://archive.org/stream/NoExit/NoExit_djvu.txt) which depicts existentialist hell as a place where no one is capable of making any decisions.